# Creating dynamic setting from list of Projects

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to create a setting in an multi-project SBT build that is dynamically produced from a list of `Project`s.

I have a task key called `riffRaffArtifactResources` of type `TaskKey[Seq[(File, String)]]` and I'd like to create a function that has a signature of `Seq[Project] => Seq[Setting[_]]` and returns the settings required based on the list of projects provided.

I can set this by hand - something like this works but is lengthy and error prone:

```
riffRaffArtifactResources := Seq(
      (riffRaffPackageType in admin).value -> s"${(name in admin).value}/${(riffRaffPackageType in admin).value.getName}",
      (riffRaffPackageType in adminJobs).value -> s"${(name in adminJobs).value}/${(riffRaffPackageType in adminJobs).value.getName}",
      (riffRaffPackageType in applications).value -> s"${(name in applications).value}/${(riffRaffPackageType in applications).value.getName}",
      (riffRaffPackageType in archive).value -> s"${(name in archive).value}/${(riffRaffPackageType in archive).value.getName}",
      (riffRaffPackageType in article).value -> s"${(name in article).value}/${(riffRaffPackageType in article).value.getName}",
      (riffRaffPackageType in commercial).value -> s"${(name in commercial).value}/${(riffRaffPackageType in commercial).value.getName}",
      (riffRaffPackageType in diagnostics).value -> s"${(name in diagnostics).value}/${(riffRaffPackageType in diagnostics).value.getName}",
      (riffRaffPackageType in discussion).value -> s"${(name in discussion).value}/${(riffRaffPackageType in discussion).value.getName}",
      (riffRaffPackageType in identity).value -> s"${(name in identity).value}/${(riffRaffPackageType in identity).value.getName}",
      (riffRaffPackageType in facia).value -> s"${(name in facia).value}/${(riffRaffPackageType in facia).value.getName}",
      (riffRaffPackageType in faciaPress).value -> s"${(name in faciaPress).value}/${(riffRaffPackageType in faciaPress).value.getName}",
      (riffRaffPackageType in onward).value -> s"${(name in onward).value}/${(riffRaffPackageType in onward).value.getName}",
      (riffRaffPackageType in rss).value -> s"${(name in rss).value}/${(riffRaffPackageType in rss).value.getName}",
      (riffRaffPackageType in sport).value -> s"${(name in sport).value}/${(riffRaffPackageType in sport).value.getName}",
      baseDirectory.value / "riff-raff.yaml" -> "riff-raff.yaml"
    )
```

My initial (simplified) attempt was:

```
def uniArtifactSimple(projects: Project*): Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
  riffRaffArtifactResources := projects.toSeq.map { project =>
    val artifactFile = (riffRaffPackageType in project).value
    val projectName = (name in project).value
    artifactFile -> s"$projectName/${artifactFile.getName}"
  }
)
```

Sadly that gave me an error: `Illegal dynamic reference: project` (well actually two, one for each reference).

After quite a bit of fiddling I have wound up with something using `taskDyn` but still can't get it to compile. My latest attempt is:

```
def uniArtifact(projects: Project*): Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
  riffRaffArtifactResources := Def.taskDyn {
    val resources = projects.toSeq.map { project =>
      val artifactFile = riffRaffPackageType in project
      artifactFile.zipWith(name in project){(file, name) =>
        file.value -> s"$name/${file.value.getName}"
      }
    }
    Def.task(Def.Initialize.join(resources).value)
  }.value
)
```

Whilst my types align I clearly don't understand how the macros work well enough to structure this correctly.

The closest examples I've found in my searches are https://github.com/scalacenter/scalajs-bundler/blob/14b77c18292a9bcb05e9a204fc72adf1a75b0bf4/sbt-web-scalajs-bundler/src/main/scala/scalajsbundler/WebScalaJSBundlerPlugin.scala and https://github.com/allenai/sbt-plugins/blob/e661264de9b35aae2a0e2edbad270b4b0cf579e0/src/main/scala/org/allenai/plugins/HelperDefs.scala - however these have not helped me to actually solve this.

Alternative structures also welcome.